Is there any way to disguise a mock object as an acceptable PyQt object in Qt method parameters?
This is an MRE. You need to have pytest installed... and in fact pytest-qt won't do any harm.
import sys, pytest
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from unittest import mock 

class MyLineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setPlaceholderText('bubbles')

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Pytest MRE")
        self.setMinimumSize(400, 200)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        qle = MyLineEdit(self)
        layout.addWidget(qle)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def test_MyLineEdit_sets_a_title():
    mock_window = mock.Mock(spec=QtWidgets.QWidget)

    print(f'mock_window.__class__ {mock_window.__class__}') # says "QWidget"
    print(f'type(mock_window) {type(mock_window)}') # says "mock.Mock"

    with mock.patch('PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLineEdit.setPlaceholderText') as mock_set_placeholder:
        # with mock.patch('PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLineEdit.__init__') as mock_super_init:
            my_line_edit = MyLineEdit(mock_window)

    mock_set_placeholder.assert_called_once()
    assert False

This illustrates a recurrent problem and I'm not sure whether there's a way round it: I want to pass a mock as a parameter of a method of a PyQt class (in this case a constructor: it is the act of passing the mock to the superclass __init__ which causes the problem).
Typically, when I try to run this test I get:
E       TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
E         QLineEdit(parent: Optional[QWidget] = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Mock'
E         QLineEdit(contents: Optional[str], parent: Optional[QWidget] = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Mock'
test_grey_out_qle_exp.py:7: TypeError

I run up against this problem with many scenarios: "has unexpected type 'Mock'"...
Over and over again, during my testing of PyQt apps, I find I have to pass a real QtWidget (or other real PyQt class object). This in turn can cause all manner of problems, at worst nasty intermittent "Windows access violation" errors ... depending on what type of combination of real PyQt objects and mocks I'm trying to get results from.
I want somehow to pass a mock into the PyQt code, under a disguise. I've tried various combinations of MagicMock, spec, autospec, etc. But the PyQt code is never fooled. It appears to be checking using the built-in function type(x). However, I don't know that for sure as I can't examine any source code for this, as it appears that the PyQt modules are automatically generated from the C++ code.
One thing that occurred to me: might it be possible to patch the built-in function type()... ? Probably an unlikely solution, not least because the PyQt module is I suspect not using Python code when checking the type. However I did search on this, to no avail.
PS as illustrated in the commented-out mock.patch... line, one possible workaround is to start patching out any PyQt superclass methods which are causing problems ...
later: musicamante's suggestion
Nice idea. I tried this:
class HybridMock(QtWidgets.QWidget, mock.Mock):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

def test_MyLineEdit_sets_a_title():
    # mock_window = mock.Mock(spec=QtWidgets.QWidget)
    mock_window = HybridMock()

On running pytest this just crashes and says "Python has stopped working ..." (with no explanation). NB platform is W10. I'm not that surprised.

No experience here on unittest, yet, as an ignorant hunch: what about creating a dummy subclass of Mock that also inherits from QWidget?

Interesting! I'll certainly give that a shot. If you don't use unittest, what do you use instead? (and is it possible that whatever you do use might provide a solution?)

You are basically trying to mock C code, which won't work out of the box. Check out this question for some ideas.

@MrBeanBremen Thanks, yes I'm fairly familiar with qtbot. In fact it is quite surprising how much mocking and patching you can do with these PyQt5 classes: see the commented-out mock.patch line above: if this is uncommented the test runs OK.

Unit testing is simply irrelevant for my purposes. That said, you have to remember that you're dealing with a binding, and, to some extent, a quite delicate one. Most importantly, the parent object of a QObject (or QWidget) must be a wrapper around an actual Qt class. You cannot just "mock" its appearance as you'd do in Python, because that wouldn't be a real Qt object. Python is mostly based on duck typing, but Qt cannot do that, as it has absolutely no awareness of the Python side. If a Qt object requires another one, that must be a Qt object, not something that "looks" like one.

@musicamante Thanks for the clarification/explanation. I suspected I was probably on a wild goose chase ...


Q: Is there any way to disguise a mock object as an acceptable PyQt object in Qt method parameters?

A: No.
It is not just a matter of having "type" reporting the mock object as a QObject: the Qt library actually needs the binary contents of the object passed to be an actual QObject, with its data structures as used by Qt. The same goes for trying to replace inner methods of the Qt library with mock objects, like the with mock.patch('PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLineEdit.setPlaceholderText') as mock_set_placeholder: line - there, your mileage might vary, and you might get lucky some of the times.
So, you are in a scenario where Python "MagicMock" objects (either the native or the ones implemented in pytest's extensions) are not of much help. The thing to do is to built your own "mock" objects, and attach then accordingly to your code - you can then create classes which are themselves sub-classes of QObject, but have intermediate methods that will log any calls (and then forward the call to the Qt library).
In this example's case, if you want to assert the superclass' version of a method is being called, there is no other way than replacing, at test time, that superclass with a mock class, for example.  (And yes, in that case, a magicmock  might work).
So, you can replace at runtime the superclass of QtWidgets.QLineEdit for a class that, although also inherits from QLineEdit, replaces its __new__ method to return a mock obect instead.
In your text file, create a base-class for MyLineEdit like this:
from contextlib import contextmanager
...

QtWidgets.QLineEdit
class MockLineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        global linemock
        linemock =  mock.Mock()
        return linemock
    def __init__(self, *args):
        # code for logging any needed calls here.
        #example:
        linemock.__init__(*args)
@contextmanager 
def patchclass(cls, replacement):
    try:
        original_bases = cls.__bases__
        cls.__bases__ = replacement
        yield cls
    finally:
        cls.__bases__ = original_bases


...
def test_MyLineEdit_sets_a_title():
    mockwindow = ...

    with mock.patch('PyQt5.QtWidgets.QLineEdit.setPlaceholderText') as mock_set_placeholder:
        # the mocked class cannot, at any point, touch  any "real" Qt functions  - it can't be passed to the "layout" object: we have to fake it.
        with mock.patch('QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout'):
            with patchclass(MyLineEdit, (MockLineEdit,)):
            
                 my_line_edit = MyLineEdit(mock_window)
                 # make any assetions on MyLineEdit superclass calls
                 # using the global `linemock` variable


MyLIneEdit will now reach itself be the mocked class - ANY method called with super(). in your class has to be handcoded in the mock-parent class.
No "real" Qt calls must be made with "self" from this test-instance - any such call (as the layout.addWidget(qle) line) have to be made to mock objects.
Also, this is a simple example using a global variable to set a mock-object to be introspected at testing time - if you are running tests in parallel, that won't work - use a threading.local or contextvars.ContextVar() container so that your test code can access the mock instance created in the mock-superclass __new__ code, if needed.
